# Tooltip placement issue

Tags: css

I have a CSS tooltip set-up to appear to the right of a link when hovered over, and it is working correctly when the link all appears on one line.

However, if the linked text runs too long and goes onto the next line, the tooltip won't appear to the right of the last word any longer.

This content section of this post is an example of what I'm talking about: http://blog.betbright.com/top-stories/premier-league-tactical-analysis-and-betting-tips-four-things-we-learnt-25th-august/

Some of the links are one on line (working correctly) some are on two lines (not working).

Here is my code for this tooltip:

```
a.CTA {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
a.CTA span {
  position: absolute;
  width:110px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #00A1E0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a.CTA span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-right: 8px solid #00A1E0;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.CTA span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: The only "solution" that comes to my mind right away is to set the link display as `inline-block` to avoid the line feed. I know is not a solution but maybe could be a workfaround until find the right solution

Comment: You could place your tooltip after the anchor, remove the `position: absolute` and add a `float`. Change your CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i would do it,

```
    a.CTA {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
a.CTA span {
  position: absolute;
  width:110px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #00A1E0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a.CTA span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-right: 8px solid #00A1E0;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.CTA span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  /* left: 100%; */
  /* top: 50%; */
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

I wouldn't use top and left property, they position elements absolutely.

In the case where you have two lines top:50% positions the tooltip between the two lines.

I commented out top/left and adjusted the margin-top.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp

Best

y_s_f

Comment: Hi @PaulM if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **height.**

```
a.CTA span{
   position: absolute;
   width: 110px; /*then make adjustment here */
   color: #FFFFFF;
   background: #00A1E0;
   display: block;
   /* height: 30px; */
   line-height: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   visibility: hidden;
   border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Then the long text will be fit inside the **tooltip**.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use `float: right;` for your tooltip, then `display: inline-block;`

Comment: As @putvande said remove `position: absolute`.